# Вызов сервиса в фоне из BroadcastReceiver'а для отображения уведомлений Android 6.0.1

Tags: android, android-service, уведомления

При реализации очередного проекта столкнулся с проблемой неработоспособности сервиса, способного выводить уведомления на устройстве, который запускается в фоне из BroadcastReceiver'а по воле ManagerService'а

Задача:
Вывод уведомлений по расписанию в фоновом режиме

Решение:
Имеется фоновый сервис ManagerService, который с определённой периодичностью создаёт на устройстве расписание AlarmManager. AlarmManager в заданное время активирует AlarmReceiver запускает сервис AlarmService, способный выводить в шторку уведомлений соответствующее уведомление

Исходный код решения:

- Манифест

  ```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

  <service
      android:name=".ManagerService"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:exported="true" />
  <service
      android:name=".AlarmService"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:exported="true"
      android:permission="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

  <receiver
      android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:exported="true"
      android:permission="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <receiver
      android:name=".BootReceiver"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:exported="true"
      android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
          <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT" />

          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
  ```
- Управляющий сервис для составления расписаний ManagerService.java

  ```
  Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
  myIntent.putExtra("id",tsk.id);
  if (tsk.user.equals(myProfileUser.id)) {
      myIntent.putExtra("name", "It's time for a task:"+ tsk.name);
  }else{
      myIntent.putExtra("name", "Task began:"+tsk.name);
  }
  myIntent.putExtra("text", tsk.text);
  myIntent.putExtra("schedule", tsk.schedule);

  Long id = Long.parseLong(tsk.id.substring(1));
  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),Integer.valueOf(id.intValue()), myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

  AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
  Date dat = new Date();
  Calendar cal_alarm = Calendar.getInstance();
  Calendar cal_now = Calendar.getInstance();
  cal_now.setTime(dat);
  cal_alarm.setTime(dat);

      //Date
      String date = tsk.schedule.split("-")[3];
      cal_alarm.set(Integer.parseInt(date.split("\\.")[2]),Integer.parseInt(date.split("\\.")[1])-1,Integer.parseInt(date.split("\\.")[0]));

      //Time
      cal_alarm.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,Integer.parseInt(tsk.schedule.split("-")[1]));
      cal_alarm.set(Calendar.MINUTE,Integer.parseInt(tsk.schedule.split("-")[2]));
      cal_alarm.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);

      //Apply only if time hasn't come yet
      if (cal_alarm.getTimeInMillis() > cal_now.getTimeInMillis()) {
          alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

          //Log.i("MSERV", "Exact alarm created: "+tsk.name);

          if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23){
              if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19){
                  alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal_alarm.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
              }
              else {
                  alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal_alarm.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
              }
          }
          else {
              alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal_alarm.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
          }
      }
      Log.i("ALARM","Exact alarm created:"+cal_alarm.getTime());
  ```
- Ресивер для запуска сервиса уведомлений (в момент срабатывания) AlarmReceiver.java

  ```
  Intent service = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
  service.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
  context.startService(service);
  ```
- Сервис создания уведомления по содержимому Extras AlarmService.java

  ```
  task_id = intent.getStringExtra("id");
  task_name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
  task_text = intent.getStringExtra("text");
  task_schedule = intent.getStringExtra("schedule");
  pushNotification();
  return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;

  public void pushNotification(){
  Toast.makeText(this, "Notification", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  //NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Service.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
  PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

  NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
  builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
          .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
          //.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.vk_logo_small_white_transparent_circle))   // большая картинка
          .setTicker("It's time")  //Top tab title
          .setContentTitle(task_name) //Title inside notification
          .setContentText(task_text)   //Text inside notification
          .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());

  Notification notification;
  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 15) {
      notification = builder.getNotification(); // до API 16
  } else {
      notification = builder.build();
  }

  int DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_ID = 10046;

  NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  nManager.notify(DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
  ```

Проблема:
Неработоспособность на Некоторых устройствах Android 6.0.1 (3 устройства из 7 работают, включая ADB)

BroadcastReceiver успешно вызывается, однако сервис уведомлений AlarmService не запускается

В виду отсутствия возможности прямого подключения к устройствам на которых решение не работает для прочтения ошибок не удаётся определить причину неработоспособности сервиса уведомлений или ресивера (буду признателен совету по применению соответствующего инструмента удалённой отладки и просмотра exception'ов)

Comment: Не хватает: 
 - манифеста
 - кода который запрашивает permission

Чтобы диагностировать, посмотрите на решения по отладки логов - Bugfender, и другие

Причины куда смотреть:
- Doze mode - соответственно надо делать Foreground service
- проблемы с получение permission на системные действия
- какие-то специфичные проблемы конкретного девайса и вывода плашек

Comment: Некоторые производители повадились встраивать чудо-манагеры, прибивающие все алармы, кроме приложений из белого списка, в который юзер должен догадаться добавить и Ваше, ибо предупреждений никаких не выдаётся.

Comment: AlarmManager является самозапускающимся стойким Foreground сервисом. Задачу по созданию будильников выполняет. В большинстве случаев при успешном срабатывании Broadcast Receiver'а не запускается сам сервис AlarmService

Со всеми менеджерами договорились.

Манифест прикрепляю к тексту вопроса

Comment: Создавайте уведомление не в сервисе, а в receiver, у вас все равно данные в бандле.

Comment: А зачем AlarmService несколько раз в манифесте?

Comment: Параллельно с созданием уведомления нужно также вызывать методы, которые асинхронно работают с FireBase

Comment: Попробуйте оставить один аларм сервис в манифесте без permission

Comment: Для лога, где нет adb, рекомендую Stetho http://facebook.github.io/stetho/

Comment: Если на эмуляторе работает, значит в прошивке покопался производитель, тупо гасит: "context.startService(service);". И почему такая длинная цепочка менеджеров и сервисов? Если есть живой foreground, то в нём и выполняйте всю работу.